# How can I delete a file named ">"?

Tags: bash, quoting, filenames, rm

I was running a Python script that malfunctioned and used `sudo` to create a file named `>`.

How can I get rid of this file?

Of course, when I try `sudo rm >`, I get the error `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'`, because it thinks I'm trying to redirect the output of `rm`.

Its permissions are `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: The answers are right, of course, but in general you might consider this: how was the file created in the first place? (Of course, `sudo touch >` at a shell would give the same error.) You said it was with a Python script, presumably created by passing `">"` to some `os` function. So `sudo python <<< 'import os; os.remove(">")'` should work just fine.

Comment: This reminded me of the one bug in windows where you literally couldn't delete a file with a certain name (but there was no problem making it.)

Comment: PyRulez ooh, which?

Comment: Ironically, the answer is in the title you wrote yourself.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Any of these should work:

```
sudo rm \>
sudo rm '>'
sudo rm ">"
sudo find . -name '>' -delete
sudo find . -name '>' -exec rm {} +
```

Note that the last two commands, those using `find`, will find *all* files or directories named `>` in the current folder and all its subfolders. To avoid that, use GNU find:

```
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -name '>' -delete
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 -name '>' -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. I use `rm '>'` usually. Is there any difference between them or a preferred approach?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `find` is not like `rm` because it is recursive and will delete *every* file named `rm` under your current directory tree no matter how deep.

Comment: @rahul The first three (the `rm` variants) are all the same. It's just three different ways of protecting that file name from the shell. There isn't really a reason to prefer one over another.

Comment: Why do you suggest `find(1)`? The only problem here is that a shell metacharacter needs to be quoted. There are a million-and-one different programs that can remove a file, but using anything other than `rm(1)` is just obfuscating the answer.

Comment: @camh because I often use find for this, it is the easiest way I know to do such actions recursively. That,  and because we try to make answers comprehensive here, the next person to stumble upon this question might have slightly different needs so it's a good idea to give alternatives.

Comment: You don't need GNU find to avoid recursing. `sudo find . ! -name . -prune -name '>' -exec rm {} +`.

Comment: I agree with @camh, `find` adds nothing for answering the question asked.

Comment: @hvd I know, I just wanted to give a simpler one than the POSIX approach given in cuonglm's answer.

Comment: @PaulDraper not to the question asked,  no.  To the next user to find this who wants to delete more files or with a slightly different situation, it might. We don't answer only for the OP.

Comment: Huh, how did I miss that? I didn't copy it from cuonglm's answer. :) In that case, yeah, I see why you didn't feel the need to include it in yours.

Answer (score 18):

You can also use Python to remove it:

```
python -c 'import os;os.remove(">")'
```

With POSIX `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name '>' -exec rm -f {} +
```

Comment: Why bother? The shell provides plenty of ways to avoid interpreting `>` as output redirection.

Comment: @alexis imo it's best to know as many ways of accomplishing these simple tasks as possible. if op has another problem like this that's more difficult to solve purely with the shell, they'll have another tool in their toolbox to give it a try with

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing initially also works:

```
sudo sh -c "rm \>"
```

This is, of course, a variant on the simpler `sudo rm \>`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as a comment but it came out all on one line

```
[Harry@localhost]~% touch ">"
[Harry@localhost]~% cat > ">"
line 1
line 2
[Harry@localhost]~% cat ">"
line 1
line 2
[Harry@localhost]~% ls -l ">"
-rw-r--r-- 1 Harry Harry 14 Jun  5 12:04 >
[Harry@localhost]~% rm ">"
[Harry@localhost]~% ls -l ">"
ls: cannot access >: No such file or directory
[Harry@localhost]~%
```

Comment: This is already in terdon's answer, though...

Comment: Yes, it is partly given in tendon's answer, I agree, I just thought that this sequence is simple and made it explicit. As you'll see I tried to include it as a comment rather than an answer, but I don't know how to avoid it all coming out on one line. It also shows you don't need Python to create the file, another point also suggested in other comments.

Answer (score 0):

Quote the character so that it isn't interpreted by the shell as a redirection:

```
sudo rm '>'
```

However, if you have other files with weird characters, the safest method is to open a GUI file explorer such as `nautilus` and delete it there.